# Get video to playback in direction mouse moves

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html5-video

### I'm attempting to use a bit of Javascript to trigger video playback when the mouse moves on the x axis, but haven't been able to get it to work.

I've included [an example](https://www.studiothomas.co.uk/?feature=sandows) of what I'm trying to achieve, and the code making it possible.

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');

var x = window.innerWidth / 2;
var y = 0;

var loaded = false;

document.onclick = function(e) {
    window.parent.postMessage('feature:click', '*');
};

// function elementAtMousePosition() {
//     return document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
// }

// document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
//     var newEvent = new Event(event.type);
//     elementAtMousePosition().dispatchEvent(newEvent);
// });

document.onmousemove = function(vent) {
    event = event || window.event;
    x = event.clientX;
    y = event.clientY;

    if (loaded) {
        throttledSeek();
    }
};

var throttle = function(delay, callback) {
    var previousCall = new Date().getTime();
    return function() {
        var time = new Date().getTime();
        if ((time - previousCall) >= delay) {
            previousCall = time;
            callback.apply(null, arguments);
        }
    };
};

var seek = function() {
    var spins = 3;

    var pos = (x - (window.innerWidth / spins * 0.5)) / (window.innerWidth / spins);

    pos -= Math.floor(pos);

    video.currentTime = pos * video.duration;
};

var throttledSeek = throttle(1000 / 16, seek);

var onload = function() {
    coverVid(video, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);

    loaded = true;

    video.style.opacity = 1;

    window.onresize();

    seek();
};

video.load();

video.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function() {
  this.play();
  this.pause();

  onload();
});
```

[Link to Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EgLzpa)

I attempted to use jQuery to do something similar, but .mousemove() didn't fire frequently enough in Chrome to make that possible. Wondering what I'm missing/leaving out/being completely stupid about that makes the code & example I've provided above tick. Any advice, constructive criticism or pointers will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have forked your codepen, I don't know how exactly your seek needs to work, but now when I move the mouse, the video seeks.

here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgRjow

Modified your script a bit:

```
(function() {
   // your page initialization code here
   // the DOM will be available here
    var video = document.getElementById('deko_vid');

    var x = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var y = 0;

    var loaded = false;

    document.onclick = function(e) {
        window.parent.postMessage('feature:click', '*');
    };

    // function elementAtMousePosition() {
    //     return document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
    // }

    // document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    //     var newEvent = new Event(event.type);
    //     elementAtMousePosition().dispatchEvent(newEvent);
    // });

    document.onmousemove = function(vent) {
        event = event || window.event;
        x = event.clientX;
        y = event.clientY;

        if (loaded) {
            throttledSeek();
        }
    };


    var seek = function() {
        var spins = 3;

        var pos = (x - (window.innerWidth / spins * 0.5)) / (window.innerWidth / spins);

        pos -= Math.floor(pos);

        video.currentTime = pos * video.duration;
    };

    var throttle = function(delay, callback) {
        var previousCall = new Date().getTime();
        return function() {
            var time = new Date().getTime();
            if ((time - previousCall) >= delay) {
                previousCall = time;
                callback.apply(null, arguments);
            }
        };
    };

    var throttledSeek = throttle(1000 / 16, seek);

    function onload() {
      loaded = true;
    };

    video.load();

    video.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function() {
      this.play();
      this.pause();

      onload();
    });

})();
```

Please mention that I modified your HTML as well... I moved the ID attribute of the video source to the actual video element.

Comment: Fantastic! Basically solved my problem, thanks again!